# Setting a scanner as a global variable

Tags: java

Method at the top, is it declared as a global variable as its not actually taking in anything.

```
 public class java_1 {

   static Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

import java.util.Scanner;
```

Thats the code used to declare it, if you can declare it another way could i get a link to the documentation.

```
public class java_1 {

   static Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

   static String getLastName (String Name){
       String lastName;
       int spacePos,length;

       spacePos = fullName.indexOf("");
       length = fullName.length();
       lastName = fullName.substring(spacePos + 1);
       return lastName;
   }


   static String getInitial (String fullName){
       String initial;
       initial = fullName.substring(0,1); 
       return initial;

   }
    static String =Name (){

       String fullName;
       String userName;
       String initial;
       String lastName;

          System.out.println("name");
          fullName = stdin.nextLine();

          initial = getInitial(fullName);
          lastName = getLastName(fullName);

          userName = initial + lastName;

          System.out.println(userName);
          return userName;
      }

static String printuserName (){

       String fullName,userName,initial,lastName;

          System.out.println("enter name");
          fullName = stdin.nextLine();

          initial = getInitial(fullName);

          userName = initial + lastName;

          System.out.println("username: " + userName);
          return userName;
      }


   static int menu(){

          int choice;
            System.out.println("Input a number from the table, corresponding to the task required");
            System.out.println("1 = User name");
            System.out.println("2 = Factor");
            System.out.println("3 = Quit");

            choice = stdin.nextInt();

            while (choice != 1){
                System.out.println("Re enter");
                choice = stdin.nextInt();
        }
            return choice;
   }




      }
     }
    }
```

Comment: I answered your other question and you didn't vote for or accept the answer.

Comment: Also you should probably post the text of the error you say you're getting?

Comment: "3 = Quit" -> "Please enter a valid input".  Whoops.

Comment: I think you've changed this completely.  What is the actual question here?  You don't actually seem to be asking anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you read the menu option with `stdin.nextInt()`, there is still a newline character waiting in the scanner.  When you call `stdin.nextLine()` some time later, you get the rest of the line - which is just an empty string.  The name itself won't be read until the FOLLOWING call to `nextLine()`.

To remedy this, you should call `nextLine()` immediately after your call to `nextInt()` in the `Menu()` method, just to clear out that extra newline character.

Comment: Be aware that there are a handful of other bugs in your code.  I recommend learning to use a debugger before you go too much further with this program.

Answer (score 1):

The error is generated by this line of code, inside `getInitial()`:

```
initial = fullName.substring(0,1);
```

The StringIndexOutOfBoundsException means that `1` is beyond the end of the string (meaning the input string is empty). If you're not already familiar with line-by-line debugging in whatever IDE you're using, this would be a good time to try. You can step through your code to determine why an empty string is being passed into `getInitial()`.