# Scanner not able to scan first String

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have the following code

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int noOfTestCases = scanner.nextInt();
    String[] firstStringsList = new String[noOfTestCases];
    String[] secondStringsList = new String[noOfTestCases];
    for(int i=0;i<noOfTestCases;i++){
        firstStringsList[i] = scanner.nextLine();
        secondStringsList[i] = scanner.nextLine();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<noOfTestCases;i++){
        System.out.println("First String : " + firstStringsList[i]);
        System.out.println("Second String : " + secondStringsList[i]);
    }
}
```

and the output goes as

```
1
asd
First String : 
Second String : asd
```

i.e I first enter 1 which means I have 1 test case which involves getting `two String inputs(per test case).` But I am able to enter only 1 String which is assigned to the `secondStringsList[i]`. I am using `Intellij IDEA`. Why is this happening? Workaround?

Comment: Did you search for questions involving `nextLine()` going wrong on a `Scanner`? This exact question gets asked very often.

Comment: [Using nextInt() before nextLine()](http://christprogramming.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/java-common-mistakes-1/)

Comment: Here are two that I prepared earlier!  :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751385/setting-a-scanner-as-a-global-variable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181887/java-string-variable-using-next-or-nextline

Comment: My bad. Loads of same questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I may have fixed your Issue

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int noOfTestCases = scanner.nextInt();
        String[] firstStringsList = new String[noOfTestCases];
        String[] secondStringsList = new String[noOfTestCases];

        scanner.nextLine();


        for (int i = 0; i < noOfTestCases; i++) {
            firstStringsList[i] = scanner.nextLine();
            secondStringsList[i] = scanner.nextLine();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfTestCases; i++) {
            System.out.println("First String : " + firstStringsList[i]);
            System.out.println("Second String : " + secondStringsList[i]);
        }
    }
```